# OpenVPN: How to DHCP static IP for client base on CN(common name)?

Tags: openvpn

I am setting up OpenVPN for my company. I assign static IP addresses for clients but I have to manual create config file on server and use `ifconfig-push` to do that. Is there any way to automatically find free IP address in ip pool and assign it to client base on Common Name.

Comment: But if you did that it wouldn't be a static IP assignment.

Comment: I can auto create config file or remove IP config file when user create or delete, but I dont know what IP address used or not to provide to config file.